# JavaScript create array of Object structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

Here is my problem:

I have a JSON structure as below

```
[{
    "groupid": 29,
    "percentage": 14
}, {
    "groupid": 29,
    "percentage": 22
}, {
    "groupid": 59,
    "percentage": 66,
}]
```

and i need to convert that into as below using Javascript.

```
{
    "29": [14, 22],
    "59": [66]
}
```

Comment: Can you please show what you've been trying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reduce` the input into an object. On each iteration, create an array at the `groupid` key in the accumulator object if it doesn't exist yet, and then `push` to the array:

```js
const input = [{
    "groupid": 29,
    "percentage": 14
}, {
    "groupid": 29,
    "percentage": 22
}, {
    "groupid": 59,
    "percentage": 66,
}];
const output = input.reduce((a, { groupid, percentage }) => {
  if (!a[groupid]) a[groupid] = [];
  a[groupid].push(percentage);
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```